How to make a generic which can infer type from a function which transforms object?
The expected result on input:
const MOCK_DATA = {
  role: {
    option: 'Founder / CEO',
    text: '',
  },
  content: {
    option: 'Marketing videos',
    text: '',
  },
};

getSurveyData(MOCK_DATA)
// {
//   role: string;
//   content: string;
// }

The expected result on some other input:
const MOCK_DATA2 = {
  position: {
    option: ['Founder / CEO', 'Developer'],
    text: '',
  },
  termsConsent: true,
};

getSurveyData(MOCK_DATA2)
// {
//   position: string;
//   termsConsent: boolean;
// }

The solution I came up with is not infer the return type, so how to make a generic function which can correctly infer return type based on input value?
The top level key on input can be of type string | object | boolean | number.
Actual return type:
const surveyData: {
    [x: string]: string | boolean | number;
}

Code:
type FormValues = {
  [key: string]:
    | {
        option: string | string[];
        text: string;
      }
    | boolean
    | string
    | number
};

export const getSurveyData = (formValues: FormValues) => {

  return Object.entries(formValues).reduce(
    (
      prev: {
        [key: string]: string | boolean | number;
      },
      [key, data],
    ) => {
      let value: string | boolean | number = '';

      if (data instanceof Object) {

        if (Array.isArray(data.option)) {
          value = data.option.join(', ');

        } else {
          value = data.option;
        }
      }

      if (typeof data === 'boolean' || typeof data === 'string' || typeof data === 'number') {
        value = data;
      }

      return { ...prev, [key]: value };
    },
    {},
  );
};

Here's TS playground

You can use a mapped type for the return type. Make getSurveyData generic (as you said):
export const getSurveyData = <T extends FormValues>(formValues: T): SurveyData<T>

...and then define SurveyData so that, for each property, it detects whether a key's value matches the object type with options and text, returning the type of text (always string) if so, or passing through the property's type otherwise (a conditional type):
type SurveyData<T extends FormValues> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends { text: string } ? string : T[Key];
};

You'll need a type assertion (as SurveyData<T>) on the return value within the implementation (with the implementation in the question; it may be possible to update the implementation to avoid it).
With that, you get the desired results:
const result1 = getSurveyData(MOCK_DATA);
console.log(result1.content);
//                  ^? (property) content: string
console.log(result1.role);
//                  ^? (property) role: string

const result2 = getSurveyData(MOCK_DATA2);
console.log(result2.position);
//                  ^? (property) position: string
console.log(result2.termsConsent);
//                  ^? (property) termsConsent: boolean

Playground link

Use mapped types and conditional types.
type SimplifiedType<T> = T extends Record<string, any> ? string : T;

function getSurveyData<T extends FormValues>(x: T): {[key in keyof T]: SimplifiedType<T[key]>} {
    // …
}

